# Outline being added on hover

Tags: css, hover, outline

I am creating a "back to top" button for my website. When I hover over the `<a>` a blue outline appears, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. What am I leaving out?

Here is what it looks like in its regular state:
[image]

And on hover:
[image]

The HTML:

```
<p id="back-top">
    <a href="#top"><span></span>Back to Top</a>
</p>
```

The CSS:

```
#back-top {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 100px;
}
#back-top a {
  width: 70px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font: 11px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #bbb;
  /* transition */
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
#back-top a:hover {
  color: #004276;
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
#back-top a:hover span {
  background-color: #777;
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important;
}
#back-top a span {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background: url("../images/BackToTop.png") no-repeat center center;
  /* transition */
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: did you try `border: 0` on `#back-top a:hover`? Also, what browser? I don't see it in chrome. It also looks like `background-color: #777;` of `#back-top a:hover span` may be showing beneath the image

Comment: try adding your outline:none..etc. rule also to -> a, a:active, a:focus, a:link

Comment: wait! I think it might be your SPAN's background color on hover actually.. remove this rule: background-color: #777;

Comment: @webkit: That was it! (The background-color). If you write it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you've added a background color to your SPAN on hover.

since you have a background image with a border radius on top of it,
then background color shows through under it.

to fix it just remove the following from your css:

```
#back-top a:hover span {
  background-color: #777;  /* REMOVE THIS LINE */
  outline: none !important;
  border: none !important;
}
```

good luck!